# 3 images for drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

as a small assignment, i am trying to build something like hotornot.com, but instead of 1 image with a rating function, i am trying to place 3 images in line, and underneath each image is a ratings (5 star module), and a voting option.. the goal is sort of choosing between the 3 images, and many users can vote on it..

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to build something like that, would be to use nodes with image fields (using CCK), one for each picture and then use [fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) to create the voting widget.

The rest is just a matter of styling/theming.

Comment: I tried, but i am trying to have 3 images in line (horizontal), and asking the user to PICK 1.. (vote 1 of the 3).. and that vote gets stored in the users database, and they can view the results..

i ve been trying to use cck to help me out with that.. but moving slowly so far

Comment: i am new at drupal.. so not sure what you mean by that